# smsManager not sending texts, from pixel phone

Tags: android, smsmanager

have the weirdest issue. I have a pixel phone that will have a sms message in the sent box from the app, but it never actually sends.

Anyone ever come across an issue like this? There isn't any errors or permissions missing, as it does send to the pixel itself but that's it.

*******************UPDATE ***********************

I've tried to use this code by itself and still it won't send out.

SmsManager sms=SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage("a real phone number", null, "android is fun ", null,null);

the message is in the sent box of the pixel phone, however it does not really get sent out. i have all the permissions of send_sms.. but no error, simply does not send, only on the pixel.

Comment: Are you on Project Fi, perchance?

Comment: nope, att.  not entirely sure why it would send to an iphone. bu tnow i'm diffing my commit.. nothing stands out.  Just REALLY bizare stuff, even rebooted the phone and it still is working in this bizarre way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i figured out that the texts although were in the sent box did not actually send. no one could receive the text.

the issue is that it couldn't send any hyperlinks that were shortened like this http:// goo. gl/something would not send through.. odd issue.